# How can I add xsi:type as an XML attribute to a tag that already has an attribute using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I read a couple of `Stackoverflow` answers that suggest hardcoding the `xsi:type` to an `Element`. However, I cannot apply it to my case because it should be after the first `attribute`.

Here is my code:

```
    XmlNode paymentMethod = CreateEmptyNode(rootNode, "PaymentMethod");

    XmlAttribute paymentmethodNamespace = CreateAttribute(paymentMethod, "xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

    XmlAttribute paymentmethodType = CreateAttribute(paymentMethod, "xsi:type", "CreditTransferType");

    public XmlNode CreateEmptyNode(XmlNode parentNode, string nodeName)
    {
        var node = parentNode.OwnerDocument.CreateElement(nodeName);
        parentNode.AppendChild(node);
        return node;
    }

    public XmlAttribute CreateAttribute(XmlNode parentNode, string attributeName, string attributeValue)
    {
        var attribute = parentNode.OwnerDocument.CreateAttribute(attributeName);
        attribute.Value = attributeValue;
        parentNode.Attributes.Append(attribute);
        // parentNode.AppendChild(node);
        return attribute;
    }
```

This is what I get as a result. It omits xsi: from type:

```
   <PaymentMethod xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" type="CreditTransferType">
```

The result must be :

```
   <PaymentMethod xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="CreditTransferType">
```

Comment: In xml linq you can just parse a string in one line : XElement element = XElement.Parse("<PaymentMethod xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:type=\"CreditTransferType\"/>");

Comment: Thank you jdweng for your quick answer. It adds only the first part and it does not add the last one. This is the total result of your code:
<PaymentMethod xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

Comment: I put a break point in code and then hover over variable and see correct results.

Comment: it shows the full text when i hover over the variable. It is split in first attribute and last attribute.
Strangely, it does not apply the last attribute to the tag when I open the .xml

Comment: When saving c# isn't outputting the attribute?

Comment: Exactly it just stays with the first one. Let me know if you need screenshots, I can attach them here.

Comment: I'm using just xml linq and get correct results.